# API for Tango ADFs?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'd like to make an indoor navigation system, using `Tango` technology.
The first step is to scan the area and create an ADF file.
But once this `ADF` is created, it's like a black box. I have not found any API to work with the `ADF`.
I would like to get a matrix of the space I scanned so I can make my own algorithm and calculate where an human being can go, and then calculate the path from point A to point B.
My question is : is there any way to get information stored in an `ADF` file ?

Comment: Is the Tango SDK for Unity3D working for you? For me it crashes every 30 seconds or so. Did you have to do something special to get it to work?